# 3 columns with float left and the same width at full screen

Tags: css, css-float

I have a full screen lay-out and what I want is 3 colums with the same width and left floating.

What i have is this:

```
<div class="table_small" style="float:left; margin-right:20px;">
<p>lipsum</p></div><div class="table_small" style="float:left; margin-right:20px;">
<p>lipsum</p></div><div class="table_small" style="float:left;"><p>lipsum</p></div>
```

One div without float and with width 100% works fine.

Is it not possible to do this with divs? Do I have to use a table for this?

Comment: It _is_ possible, but this html is.. weird. I'll make you a quick example :)

Comment: You should search for duplicates before you ask a question: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bhtml%5D+3+collumn+layout&submit=search

Comment: a little tip, dont yous table tag unless you are really showing a grid.
don't build the layout with tables , use divs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need one `div` with its display set to `table` wrapped around your `p`s.

HTML

```
<div class="table_small">
    <p>lipsum</p>
    <p>lipsum</p>
    <p>lipsum</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.table_small
{
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
}

.table_small p
{
    display: table-cell;
    border: 1px dashed #000;
}
```

The parent element `<div class="table_small">` must have a set width for this to work.

[Demo for you here](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/qpDda/).

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="column1" style="float:left; left:0px; width:33%"></div>
    <div class="column2" style="float:left; left:33%; width:33%"></div>
    <div class="column3" style="float:left; left:66%; width:33%"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: He said: I want is 3 colums with the same width and left floating

Comment: I see that, but if he decides in the future to have more than 3 columns, he'll run into problems. Also, why do you have float left AND position? One or the other would work, when you set an element to float, it sets its position automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code may be can helpful to you. You can modify style properties as per your need.

```
<html>
<body style="width:100%; margin:0px;">
<div class="table_small" style="float:left; margin:0 10px; border:1px solid; width:31.7%;">
<p>lipsum</p></div>
<div class="table_small" style="float:left; margin:0 10px; border:1px solid; width:31.7%;">
<p>lipsum</p></div>
<div class="table_small" style="float:left; margin:0 10px; border:1px solid;width:31.7%;"><p>lipsum</p></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks.